# path not getting added to environment variable after script execution

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I have script which downloads the binary and update the path variable, but as soon as the script exits and I try to run the binary, it doesn't find the downloaded binary. On every system I have to source .bash_profile explicitly even though I run that command in my bash script.

```
if [[ $update_path == 0 ]]; then
  echo $"export PATH=$PATH:$target" >> ~/.bash_profile # ~/.profile
  source ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

**And I don't want to ask user to re-login.**

Comment: Can you post a sample of the `~/.bash_profile`? Is the new target present?

Comment: yes new target is present, but it is only effective when I run source /.bash_profile

Comment: well is the script the one trying to run the binary? or are you, after the script closes? source bashrc inside the script will only ever take effect outside of the script. uless you use this hack : `eval "$(cat .bashrc | tail -n +10)"`

Comment: eval "$(cat .bashrc | tail -n +10) can you explain the hack?

Comment: @SimonSudler yes new target is present

Answer (score 3):

The script execute the `source` inside its context.

Once the script ends, its context ends with it.

- So the current context doesn't hold the content of the updated `~/.bash_profile`.

You need to re-login or `source` the `~/.bash_profile` again in order to get the updated variable.

Comment: I don't want to ask user to re-login

Comment: @prashant Consider whether your approach, adding permanently to the path for your custom application only, is a sound one. It would be much better if your script puts an executable or a symbolic link or a wrapper script in one of the standard folders that are included in the PATH on a typical linux system. Given you still want to do it your way, this is an adequate answer.